# How to switch cancel and destructive alert buttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, alert

I created a simple alert and I would like to have the destructive button on the left and the 'cancel' button on the right, but I don't know how to manage it, any suggestions?

[image]

##### Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present alert") {
                showAlert.toggle()
            }
        }
        .alert("Do you want to quit?",
               isPresented: $showAlert,
               actions: {
            
            Button("No", role: .cancel) {
                //
            }
            
            Button ("Yes", role: .destructive) {
                //
            }
            
        }, message: {
            Text("You will go back to main menu")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. The alert automatically conforms to the apple [style guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/presentation/alerts) which places cancel buttons on the leading edge. Also "Cancel" and "Quit" are probably better titles for your button than "yes" and "no"

Comment: @Paulw11 I know that it's possible, i saw it a while ago

Comment: Fwiw [this](https://gist.github.com/paulw11/71535ce7e232e13e3aec6b5c0effa893) is clearer and more compliant with the HID guidelines

Comment: if you saw it some where else, it is probably a custom alert. Because this is a guideline for Swiftui.

Comment: I think I saw it with the old deprecated Alert :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a little research and the only solution I found is to use the deprecated struct Alert that still works but may not do so in the future, this is the code:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Do you want to leave the game?"),
                message: Text("You will go back to the main menu."),
                primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Yes"), action: {
                    // code here
                }),
                secondaryButton: .default(Text("No")) //<-- use default here
            )
        }
```

Pay attention, you have to use .default() as a 'cancel' button, you cannot use .cancel()

[image]

Comment: Alert is deprecated. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert

Comment: ...as already stated in the answer.